# how to continue same background sound for two splash activity

Tags: android

My android app is having two splash screen. first screen with company name for 2 sec and than screen with project name as second splash screen for 5 sec. 
I want to play one single sound as the app will start till second splash gets over i.e 
continuous for 7 sec.
 How can i achieve this???

Comment: Check [this url](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App) for how to create an animated splash screen. Not your case but might be of a use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use just one splash screen and change the background in desired time intervals and play your sound file at the same time.

```
    ImageView splashImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.YourFirstSplash);
//after 2seconds call this method:
    splashImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YourSecondSplash);
//after 5seconds call method to close the splash screen
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start a Service to play the music in the background so that it will play continuously throughout the 2 splash screens or combine the 2 splash screen into one activity and run the music on that screen.

Answer (score 1):

try not changing the Activity just change the layout for the activity using

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.first_screen);
// Provide 2 Sec of wait

setContentView(R.layout.sec_screen)
//provide 5 sec of wait
```

after 2 sec. This will Change The View But your activity remains same and the music you wish to play has no effect on it.

Comment: Thanks , I gonna try this. :)